# Why am I getting this error? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This is my php code:

```
<?php 
$group = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'groupchooser', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, 
FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "password", "id3234074_posts");

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT TOP 10 titles, comments * FROM $group ');

$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));

$row = $stmt->fetch();


if($row['id'] == ''){
header('Location: ./');
exit;
}
?>
```

I have have tried without using prepare and it still gets me a similar error about the boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You have three mistakes in your code:

`SELECT TOP X` is [SQL Server](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) syntax, but judging by the API in your code, you're using MySQL, so you need to use `LIMIT X`.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT titles, comments FROM $group LIMIT 10');
```

Further, you're biding parameters to the query via `execute()`, but have no placeholders in it. So, you need to either add them with `bind_param()` (for example, a `WHERE` clause), or remove the parameters from `execute()`:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT titles, comments FROM $group LIMIT 10 WHERE id = ?');

$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET["id"]);

$stmt->execute();
```

Or

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT titles, comments FROM $group LIMIT 10');

$stmt->execute();
```

Lastly, you have a couple of fields you're selecting *and* the wildcard `*`. You can have this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT titles, comments FROM $group LIMIT 10');
```

to select `titles` and `comments`, or this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM $group LIMIT 10');
```

to select *all* the fields in the `$group` table.

---

Sidenote: you're directly embedding client data into your query, and  `filter_input()` isn't helping. You need to be absolutely, positively, 100% sure of what you're inputting into you're query. A safer option could be to have a list of possible `groups`, and only allow the user to pick one of them:

```
$group = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'groupchooser', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, 
FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$groups = ["group1", "group2"];
if (!in_array($group, $groups)) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid group");
}
```

Comment: thx for the help. And thx for the input, I already have a select in my html code that only allows people to select specific groups. But even after I made the changes you pointed out it still gave me the same error                                   f

Comment: @AndréRöygaard Sorry, I forgot to delete the asterisks. Try now. About the groups: the data the client is sending is **completely** editable, it doesn't matter what the options are in the select. You **need** to do a server-side check.

Comment: All Im really trying to do is get the table "group" from the server and echo the rows "titles" and "comments". I am pretty new at this sry XD

Comment: you have a lot of mistakes as well. execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']) is PDO syntax, but judging by the API in his code, he is  using mysqli

Comment: @YourCommonSense right, completely missed that. I fixed it, thanks!